# How to programmatically bind a (dependency) property of a control that's inside a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

The `TextBlock` resides in a `DataTemplate`, thus I can't refer to it by its name. So how do I bind its (e.g.) `Text` property programmatically?

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyCustomControl" ... >
    ...
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MyCustomControl : UserControl {
    ...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource", typeof (IEnumerable),
                                    typeof (MyCustomControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

    public IEnumerable DataSource {
        get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MemberPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MemberPath", typeof (string),
                                    typeof (MyCustomControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string MemberPath {
        get { return (string) GetValue(MemberPathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MemberPathProperty, value); }
    }
    ...
    public MyCustomControl() {
        InitializeComponent();

        var binding = new Binding(MemberPath);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(/*how do I refer to the TextBlock here ???*/,
                                     TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    }
    ...
}
```

Intended usage example:

```
<my:MyCustomControl DataSource="{Binding Path=SomeModelCollection}" MemberPath="Name"
```

Where `SomeModelCollection` is some data-model property like `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>` (`SomeModel` has a property called `Name`)

Comment: What does d 'Textblock' intend to show.. What to be as 'MemberPath'.. What was d itemsource for this..

Comment: @Sankarann - I added `MemberPath` - it's intended to bind the `Path` property of the `TextBlock` from outside (i.e. in the XAML where I embed `MyCustomControl`

Comment: @Sankarann - also added an intended usage example

Comment: So `MemberPath` has only one value and that to bind with `TextBox.Text`.. it means all the List Items will show the same value which is in the `MemberPath`.. am i right?

Comment: Here every `ListItem` holds `MyModel` as Its `DataContext`. So if you want to Bind the `Name` you can just use `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>`... Still am not clear with How your relating with `MemberPath` and `TextBlock.Text`..

Comment: @Sankarann - no, `MemberPath` holds the name of path to bind to, in this example - `SomeModel` has a property called "Name" (i.e. `MemberPath == "Name"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `TextBlock` using `VisualTreeHelper`. This method will get you all TextBlockes present in Visual tree of listBoxItem:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj)
            where T : DependencyObject
{
   if( depObj != null )
   {
       for( int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( depObj ); i++ )
       {
          DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( depObj, i );
          if( child != null && child is T )
          {
              yield return (T)child;
          }

          foreach( T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>( child ) )
          {
             yield return childOfChild;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
TextBlock textBlock = FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(listBoxItem)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

**But I would still suggest to do the binding in XAML instead of doing it in code behind.**

In case `ItemSource` is `ObservableCollection<MyModel>` and `MyModel` contains property `Name`, it can be done in XAML like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
   </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Since `DataContext` of `ListBoxItem` will be `MyModel`, hence you can bind directly to Name property like mentioned above.

Comment: How can I do it in the XAML ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: But I bind it to `ObservableCollection<MyModel>`, where `MyModel` has a `string` field called `Name`. It's not a simple `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Comment: And the provided code doesn't work - first, it must be called only after the constructor is finished, and second it must be called every time the list is changed, so it's not really a binding...

Comment: You need then simple `"{Binding Name}"`. Check update in answer.